# php multiple querys in while in while

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli, while-loop

I got a problem that I don't seem to be able to find a solution for.

I'm currently working with wordpress where I'm writing a plugin that can present on the admin dashboard which "projects" the current user is working on. For that I need 2 queries but for some reason the site stops working when querying the second query.

I got 3 tables

**wp_posts (post_name and ID)**

**wp_cpm_user_role (project_id and user_id)**

**wp_users (ID and login_login)**

Where:

```
wp_posts.ID = wp_cpm_user_role.project_id
```

And:

```
wp_cpm_user_role.user_id 0 wp_users.ID
```

My code so far

```
Function assigned_projects(){
//database information
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Password1";
    $dbname = "wordpress";

    //Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
    {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
    }

//First query
    $sql = "SELECT wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.ID 
FROM wordpress.wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE post_type = 'cpm_project' AND meta_key = '_project_active' AND meta_value = 'yes'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//get login name on current user
    $user = $current_user->user_login;

    //prepare table for presentation
            echo '<table class="HOTtable">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="tdcenter">Project name<hr></td>';
            echo '<td class="tdright">Quick link<hr></td>';
            echo '</tr>';

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
            //output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                    $name = $row["post_name"];
                    $ID = $row["ID"];

        //create a direct link to the project url
                    $url = "https://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=cpm_projects&tab=project&action=overview&pid=" . $ID;

        //second query to match users with projects
                    $sql1 = "SELECT wp_cpm_user_role.user_id, wp_cpm_user_role.project_id, wp_users.user_login FROM wordpress.wp_cpm_user_role INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_cpm_user_role.user_id = wp_users.ID WHERE wp_cpm_user_role.project_id =" . $ID;
                    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

                    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                            if ($user == $row1["user_login"] AND $ID == $row1["project_id"])
                            {
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                    echo '<td class="tdcenter">' . $name . '<hr></td>';
                                    echo '<td class="tdright"><a href=' . $url . '>I am the link</a><hr></td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    echo '</table>';
    $conn->close;
}
```

Comment: Does you source code go past the second query? Did you have a look at the MySQL error log?

Comment: Try echo $sql1; and run it in PHPMyAdmin to see if there is any error

Answer (score -1):

I tried to delete my code and copy the code from my original post, and it works now...

Coding is confusing. But thank you for taking your time :)